# Multiples opciones en un case de un switch javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

quisiera saber si es posible hacer un switch y que en un case entre cuando se cumpla con varias opciones, algo como lo siguienttexto en negritae en el primer case

```js
    let codigoVariable = 2
    switch (codigoVariable) {
      case 1 || 2 || 3:
        console.log('hola')
        break
      case 4:
        console.log('adios')
        break

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al probar tu código en *fragmento de código (code snippet)* se ve que no funciona, pero puedes colocar los diferentes valores que deseas aceptar, sin instrucciones y sin break para agruparlos:

```js
    let codigoVariable = 2
    switch (codigoVariable) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        console.log('hola')
        break
      case 4:
        console.log('adios')
        break
      default:
        console.log('Nada');
    }
```

También puedes evaluar si el resultado es verdadero, colocando condiciones como lo harías en un if:

```js
        let codigoVariable = 2
        switch (true) {
          case codigoVariable >= 1 && codigoVariable <= 3:
            console.log('hola')
            break
          case codigoVariable = 4:
            console.log('adios')
            break
          default:
            console.log('Nada');
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracia, me funcionó perfecto (y)

Answer (score 1):

No tiene sentido hacer un `switch` para tomar una acción binaria. Para el caso específico que pones, la solución es un `if` y te lo simplifico con un arreglo

```
const posibilidades  = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const codigoVariable = 2;

if ( posibilidades.includes( codigoVariable ) ) {
   console.log( 'Hola' );
} else {
   console.log( 'Adiós' );
}
```

Un `switch` por lo general se utiliza cuando cada una de las opciones que tome la variable es una acción distinta, en tu caso son dos, hola y adiós, por eso reduce a un `if else`

Answer (score 1):

Aunque ya tienes 2 buenas respuestas, se me ocurre esta forma *no usual* de hacerlo:

```js
let opciones = [1, 2, 3];

let codigoVariable = 2

switch (true) {
  case opciones.includes(codigoVariable):
    console.log('hola');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('adios');
    break;
}


codigoVariable = 4

switch (true) {
  case opciones.includes(codigoVariable):
    console.log('hola');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('adios');
    break;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Digo no usual, porque normalmente el bloque `switch case` se utiliza para separar las opciones individualizadas. Sin embargo, Javascript es bastante flexible para hacer esto que planteo. ¿La utilidad? eso lo defines tú de acuerdo a tu necesidad y el ambiente en el que trabajes, ya que no todos podrían entender a la primera lo que sucede allí.