# ¿Como puedo usar un SWITCH dentro de un FUNCTION con 2 argumentos en JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, function, switch

Hola compañeros programadores.

Tengo la siguiente función la cual tiene un if para encontrar el número mayor entre 2 argumentos y arroja correctamente las respuestas según las condiciones que se le de:

```
function numeroMayor (num1, num2) {
  if (num1 > num2) {
    return num1 + " es mayor que " + num2;
  } else if (num1 < num2) {
    return  num2 + " es mayor que " + num1;
  } else {
    return num1 + " y " + num2 + " son números iguales.";
  }
}
console.log(numeroMayor(15, 5));
```

Pero no quiero usarla con un if sino con un switch (El ejercicio es más largo y se generan demasiados ELSE IF)... Al tener la función 2 argumentos, no sé como se formula correctamente. Intenté hacer lo siguiente pero la consola no imprime correctamente las respuestas según las condiciones... Ejemplo: 10 > 5 debería dar como resultado: 10 es mayor que 5. Pero en vez de esto, la consola me arroja: 10 y 5 son números iguales. Por lo cual evidentemente estoy formulando mal el SWITCH. ¡Aiudaaa! :'(

```
function numeroMayor (num1, num2) {
  switch (numeroMayor) {
    case (num1 > num2):
      return num1 + " es mayor que " + num2;
      break;
    case (num1 < num2):
      return  num2 + " es mayor que " + num1;
      break;
    default:
      return num1 + " y " + num2 + " son números iguales.";
    }
}
console.log(numeroMayor(10, 5));
```

En resumidas cuentas mi pregunta es: ¿Como hago el ejercicio 1 con SWITCH en vez de IF? (soy nuevo programando y me surgió esta duda). Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: "No funciona" es una pésima descripción de un problema. ¿Qué error sale? Revisaste la consola del navegador para ver si hay errores?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, ya corregí la pregunta, espero se entienda. ¿Me ayudas por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ¿Cómo está estructurado «switch-case»?

La forma en la que trabaja `switch-case` [ver fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) es la siguiente:

```javascript
switch (expresión) {
  case valor1:
    //Declaraciones ejecutadas cuando el resultado de expresión coincide con el valor1
    [break;]
  case valor2:
    //Declaraciones ejecutadas cuando el resultado de expresión coincide con el valor2
    [break;]
  ...
```

##### Error cometido

En tu caso, estás utilizando `numeroMayor` como `expresión`, lo cual no tiene sentido ya que `numeroMayor` es el nombre de la función y no es una variable ni expresión, tampoco tiene una funcionalidad recursiva.

##### Ejemplo para entender mejor su funcionamiento

Lo que podrías hacer, pero aún así es incompleto es poner en la expresión las variables que las que quieres ponder condiciones, `num1` y `num2`, por ejemplo:

```javascript
function numeroMayor (num1, num2) {
  switch (num2-num1) {
    case (1): // cuando num2-num1=1
      return num1 + " es mayor que " + num2 + " en 1 cantidad";
    case (-1): // cuando num2-num1=-1
      return  num2 + " es mayor que " + num1 + " en 1 cantidad";
    default:
      return num1 + " y " + num2 + " son números iguales.";
    }
}
console.log(numeroMayor(6, 5));
```

**La limitación** está en que en el case no puedes usar el valor de la expresión para saber si es mayor o menor que... Pero como se explica en [Stackoverflow: Multiples opciones en un case de un switch javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/374031/170764) es posible utilizar comparaciones de la siguiente forma:

#### Solución

La respuesta es utilizar siempre verdadero (`true`) en la expresión del «switch-case». De esta forma puedes poner distintas expresiones en cada caso.

```javascript
function numeroMayor (num1, num2) {
  switch (true) {
    case (num1 > num2):
      return num1 + " es mayor que " + num2;
    case (num1 < num2):
      return  num2 + " es mayor que " + num1;
    default:
      return num1 + " y " + num2 + " son números iguales.";
    }
}
console.log(numeroMayor(10, 10));
```

Comment: Curioso el sistema, pero ¿en qué mejora eso un if/else? Me parece abusar del switch para algo para lo que no está diseñado, consiguiendo que sea más complejo de leer, aunque sea por la sorpresa inicial. Yo no lo metería como solución, sino como apaño que cumple lo que se pide.

Comment: Tengo entendido que todo "switch" está construido sobre "if" por detrás, al menos en cuanto a la lógica, por lo que siempre sería más lento. Los lenguajes de programación de bajo nivel probablemente no tengan "switch" precisamente por que están enfocados en eficiencia. Esta clausula tiene más bien una finalidad de lenguaje de alto nivel para hacer un código más ameno, corto y entendible en vez de poner cientos de "if else" en serie que puede tomar mucho más código escrito [En esta otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259830/13636459) muestran una tabla de velocidades de ejecución.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    let codigoVariable = prompt ("teclea un numero (1,2,3)");
    switch (codigoVariable) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        console.log('hola')
        break
      case 4:
        console.log('adios')
        break
      default:
        console.log('Nada');
    }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).